# Django : model instance url is appending to the current url

Tags: django

i have some link in a template to which i want to point to particular url.

template is accessed at url : **loacalhost:8000/account/profile**

```
{% for poll in voted_poll_list %}
    <h4><a href="{{ poll.link_url }}">{{ poll.title }}</a> </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

in models.py i have created the url for the poll objects to be used in a template.

```
def link_url(self):
           return "polls/"+ "allcat/" +str(self.id)
```

the problem is when a link in template is clicked it is point to the **loacalhost:8000/account/profile/polls/allcat/1** instead of **loacalhost:8000/polls/allcat/1** which matches to url pattern

```
url(r'^polls/(\w+)/(?P<pid>[-\d]+)/', 'pollsite.views.poll_detail', name='detail_poll'),
```

the problem is link url of object is appended to current url. how can i avoid this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try leading the url with a forward slash:

```
def link_url(self):
           return "/polls/allcat/" +str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

@garnertb 's solution works, but you should probably look into using the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) function rather than hardcoding your url.

Something like:

```
return reverse('detail_poll', self.id)
```

This will not only take care of the leading slash, but also avoid trouble if you ever start changing your url configuration.